# Passing data to another ViewController without moving to the ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a sign up flow with different view controllers. I take input from user in ViewController1, move to the next view controller (ViewController2), and pass the data to the last view controller (for e.g ViewController5).

The issue is I can pass my data to the next view controller but I can’t pass it to the last view controller, as in:

```
// Move to Second View of the flow.
let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: “SecondViewController“) as! SecondViewController
secondViewController.dataText = dataText!
self.navigationController?.show(secondViewController, sender: nil)

// Pass the data to the last View of the flow.
let fifthViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: “FifthViewController“) as! FifthViewController
fifthViewController.dataText = emailText!
```

The `dataText` would pass to the `SecondViewController` but not the `FifthViewController`. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use class and create singleton object to store data and retrieve
in fifth view controller

```
class SingletonClass {
    var sharedInstance: SingletonClass {
          struct Static {
               static let instance = SingletonClass()
          }
          return Static.instance
     }
     var dataText : String = ""
}
```

now you can store data in singleton object like this as below

```
 let singleTon = SingletonClass()
 singleTon.sharedInstance.dataText = "store data"
```

and use like this in your fifthViewController

```
  let singleTon = SingletonClass()
  print(singleTon.sharedInstance.dataText)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your Appdelegate.swift file create a instance of FifthViewController like this

```
'var fifthViewController: FifthViewController?'
```

in your view controller from where you want to pass data

```
'let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate'
```

'

```
appDelegate.fifthViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: “ FifthViewController“) as! FifthViewController
appDelegate.fifthViewController.dataText = emailText!
```

'

when ever you want to push FifthViewController use Appdelegte refrence of this controller like this

```
'self.navigationController?.pushViewController(appDelegate.fifthViewController!, animated: true)'
```

Comment: This should work only if I want to push the view controller from where the data is sent. I didn’t want to do that.